# Inserting incrementing date into separate Select query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have inherited the following query :-

```
SELECT
 d.dt --date
,fuel --vchar
,SUM(revenue) revenue --number

FROM
    (
    SELECT
     ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'mm'),-ROWNUM + 1)-1 dt     
    FROM dual    
    ) d

<<SNIP>> 

WHERE rn = 1    

GROUP BY
 d.dt
,fuel;
```

This returns a summed amount for the previous month.

Is it possible to somehow loop this so that it returns results for specific historical days. A static example would be :-

```
SELECT
 d.dt --date
,fuel --vchar
,SUM(revenue) revenue --number

FROM
    (
    SELECT to_date('31-08-2017', 'dd-MM-yyyy') dt     
    FROM dual    
    ) d

<<SNIP>> 

WHERE rn = 1    

GROUP BY
 d.dt
,fuel;
```

I've been able to write the code to generate the dates I'm interested in :-

```
DECLARE
    startdate   DATE := TO_DATE('31/08/2016','dd/mm/yyyy');
    enddate     DATE := trunc(SYSDATE,'MM') - 1;
    usedate     DATE := enddate;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        usedate := add_months(usedate,-1);
        dbms_output.put_line(usedate);
        EXIT WHEN usedate <= startdate;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

...with usedate being the date in question, but I'm unclear how to use these dates in the original query.

Comment: where is revenue and fuel coming from ? show somev sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below. Read comments inline.

```
DECLARE
  startdate DATE := TO_DATE('31/08/2016','dd/mm/yyyy');
  enddate   DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM') - 1;
  usedate   DATE := enddate;
--Record to hold resultset from the Select query.
type UserInfo     IS      record
  (
    dt     DATE,
    fuel   VARCHAR2(100),
    revnue NUMBER );
TYPE v_UserInfo
IS
  TABLE OF USerinfo INDEX BY pls_integer;
  UserRecord UserInfo;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    usedate := add_months(usedate,-1);
    dbms_output.put_line(usedate);
    EXIT  WHEN usedate <= startdate;

    --Using usedate in select statement 

     SELECT * 
     BULK COLLECT    INTO UserRecord
    from (
          SELECT d.dt       ,
          fuel, --- This column is coming from another table
          SUM(revenue)      --- This column is coming from another table
     FROM
        ( SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(usedate,'mm'),-ROWNUM + 1)-1 dt FROM dual
        ) d); --Make join with the table having columns in select query

      FOR i IN 1..UserRecord.count
      loop
       --Displaying records of select staement
       dbms_ouput.put_line(UserRecord(i).dt ||UserRecord(i).fuel || UserRecord(i).revnue);
      end loop;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

PS: Not tested.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'm getting a "PLS-00497: cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in INTO list" error. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1936588 Please try now.

Comment: Sorry, now I get "ORA-00904: "REVENUE": invalid identifier" on line "SUM(revenue) revenue"

Comment: @user1936588 try now,

Comment: Same error on same line. Please note the edits to the end of my original code, as may be relevant.

Comment: @user1936588 It looks like you are posting incomplete select query. Either you need to post full query or do some analysis as in why it saying invalid identifier, Looping logic you can follow, If you just compile what i posted, it should work. An ofcourse you can see the only date part is coming from dual. Other columns are coming from another table so include those tables as wel

Answer (score 0):

You missing the number of months between your start date and use date. Not sure how you were able to generate your dates with your code as usedate := add_months(usedate,-1); will always give you the static value = 28-FEB-18.
In my example I use a bit different start date, which I suggest for your testing:

```
 SELECT start_date
      , end_date
      , add_months(use_date,-LEVEL) stop_date
      , MONTHS_BETWEEN(use_date, start_date) months_diff -- increment number
  FROM
  (
   SELECT TO_DATE('31/08/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')   start_date 
        , trunc(SYSDATE,'MM')-1                end_date
        , add_months(trunc(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,-1) use_date
    FROM dual
 )
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(use_date, start_date) -- will run 6 times = months_diff --
/

START_DATE  END_DATE    STOP_DATE   MONTHS_DIFF
--------------------------------------------------
31-AUG-17   31-MAR-18   31-JAN-18   6
31-AUG-17   31-MAR-18   31-DEC-17   6
31-AUG-17   31-MAR-18   30-NOV-17   6
31-AUG-17   31-MAR-18   31-OCT-17   6
31-AUG-17   31-MAR-18   30-SEP-17   6
31-AUG-17   31-MAR-18   31-AUG-17   6  <<-- stopped here as stop_date equals to start date
```